# Multitouch gestures with laptop touchpad in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, laptop, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm trying to use multitouch gestures on my Acer Aspire VN7-791G with Kubuntu 16.04 installed. Using two fingers to scroll horizontally and vertically works well, so does using three fingers as a middle click. I could set this up quite easily in the system settings. 
But how can I connect a gesture like "swipe right with three fingers" to "move to next virtual desktop"? I already have a shortcut for this (`CTRL+ALT+RIGHT`). Now I only need to connect this gesture to the shortcut. But how?
I tried touchégg and easystroke but they didn't work that well. Is there an easier solution now?